Access .Net COM object from Python
I'm trying to build a python program to access the functions/properties built in .Net libraries (dll files). I'm using the MSL-LoadLib module from here. With the help from the author, everything worked until the python server needs to access the properties of a COM object. So basically in my python script, I get a COM object, but cannot access its properties. I have a C# program using the same libraries, and when I debug through it, I saw its Dynamic View has all the properties I want to access, as in the attached picture. I tried many ways, like getattr to get the attributes of the object, or call getproperty/getvalue, but none of them worked. How can I access them from the same object "cx" in my python codes? Any suggestion is appreciated! Thanks!

